# Visual Studio projects. Running NVIDIA Optical Flow samples

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nvidia

I have installed  [NVIDIA Optical Flow SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/opticalflow-sdk). And with README file was able to build samples, but not run them.

1. First question, there is build folder, which contains all the samples. But I cannot run it by default. Should it work at all with default run? I have next message.
   [image]
2. I can change startup project (doesn't know what does it mean) to run one of the samples. And I have next screen. Seems like there is no errors, but i don't understand how samples actually to run? Maybe I need to add extra params?

[image: ddd]

Comment: In the first picture you selected a project that is not executable so you can't run it. ALL_BUILD is a structural project that forces all other targets to build. Change the startup project to something that is executable,

Comment: The second screen you have to pass command line parameters to the program to run. The output explains what is needed. In Visual Studio the debugging setting of the target options allows you to enter the command line options.

Comment: target means the same as project in Visual Studio. I used CMake terminology

Comment: The documentation for setting the command line arguments in Visual Studio is here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/project-settings-for-a-cpp-debug-configuration?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/project-settings-for-a-cpp-debug-configuration?view=vs-2019) Command Arguments is what you need put your command line arguments as per the instructions printed on the window that you have shown.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks man. I would like to avoid VS at all. But don't get how Windows works. I'm wondering why my usual "Command Prompt" doesn't have cmake, which is working fine throw VS. I know there is "Command Prompt for VS" which has it. (That's why i'm here with VS screens BTW)) But how I can tell any  terminal shell to access cmake and other dependencies from VS?

Comment: You could use [devenv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019) to run the program and use [/useenv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/useenv-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)  to set lib path.

Comment: At this point since the code is already built you probably could open a cmd.exe window and cd to the folder and run the code directly.